# Face ID authentication for Cordova Hybrid app

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, face-id

I am developing a Hybrid application for Android & IOS in which I have to add Biometrics `(Touch ID/Face ID)` functionality. I have implemented Touch ID for Android & IOS using `Cordova` plugin but its not working for Face ID in android.

Does android allow third party hybrid apps to use Face ID for authentication?